# How to wrap a group of controls as a unit in cshtml / razor?

Tags: html, razor

My html is pretty rusty. Basically, I'm getting a list of items (from a data table) and adding radio buttons along with the loaded item text and an icon for the user to choose. Everything is fine, except that I want the radio button, the accompanying text, and the icon to wrap as a group.

As an example, on a small screen with many choices, it displays like:

```
<O> Item One <icon>  <O> Item Two <icon>  <O> Item Three
<icon>  <O> Item Four <icon>  <O> Item Five <icon>  <O>
Item Six <icon>
```

But I want it to wrap at my groups, more like this:

```
<O> Item One <icon>  <O> Item Two <icon>
<O> Item Three <icon>  <O> Item Four <icon>
<O> Item Five <icon>  <O> Item Six <icon>
```

And, of course the labels aren't this uniform in size and I want the breaks to be dynamic so if the user is using a large monitor the items are all on 1 line, or 2 lines, etc.

So, the question comes down to, is there an element I can wrap each group in, have wrapping turned off within the group, and force wrapping to happen between groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each group in a `span` tag with the CSS style `white-space: nowrap`.  This forces all the elements in the same group to stay on the same line, but lets the browser lay out the groups.

Comment: Perfect! I had tried to add that style directly to a span, and it complained that it wasn't valid. Didn't think adding it through a CSS class would have an effect.